# android-graphview conflicts with viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-graphview

I have an activity that holds 2 fragments with a viewpager to scroll between them. In the first fragment i have an mapfragment and a graphview which is scalable. In the second one, i have some basic stuff like textviews and such. Now, if i want to browse in my graphview, i scroll a little bit and then the viewpager takes over and takes me to the other fragment. Is there a way on how i can fix this?

[image: this is my UI]

Comment: Try to catch the swipe event and prevent it from propagating to ViewPager if it occurred on GraphView.

Comment: will be fixed in 4.0.1 https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/issues/276

Comment: looking forward to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just hit a similar issue, while switching from v3.1.3 to v4.0.0. Resolved my own issue by simply capturing and passing any clicks up the food chain (**getRootView()**) eg.

```
    graphView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.v(TAG, "GraphView Click - pass event up");
            mGraphType = !mGraphType;
            invalidateViews(view.getRootView());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have comment privileges yet so can someone please ask this in a comment:

"Has this issue been resolved in 4.01 and if not have you successfully implemented a work around?"

Thank you.